# How to open .zip.tmp file?

Tags: zip, tmp

Recently, I purchased the MathTimePro 2 font for my LaTeX document. I downloaded it and opened it, but nothing happened. The downloaded file is called `mtp2fonts.zip.tmp`, it seems like a temporary zip file and I need to access all the files inside it by extracting them. The sales manager said they used this format to ensure compatibility with PCTeX, but I want to use MiKTeX instead. My OS is **Windows 10**. How can I remove `.tmp` from the file name to extract the contents of `mtp2fonts.zip`?